# Increase upload size on Nginx

Tags: php, apache, nginx, plesk

I keep getting "The connection was reset" when trying to upload a large file (around 135MB). When I look at the "last_nginx.conf" of the website conf directory it says "client_max_body_size 128m;" I assume that is the upload limit, so how/where do I change it? It says not to bother changing the  value in that file because it will only be overwritten. Btw Nginx is enabled via Plesk admin panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to change vhosts nginx file is this :

```
mkdir /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/custom/domain

cp /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/default/domain/nginxDomainVirtualHost.php /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/custom/domain/
```

add in `/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/custom/domain/nginxDomainVirtualHost.php`:

```
<?php if (file_exists($VAR->domain->physicalHosting->vhostDir . '/conf/nginx.conf')): ?>
include <?php echo $VAR->domain->physicalHosting->vhostDir;?>/conf/nginx.conf;
<?php endif ?>
```

`/usr/local/psa/admin/bin/httpdmng --reconfigure-all #` to apply new configuration for all domains

As result, if domain has `conf/nginx.conf` - it will be included into virtual host config.

Answer (score -2):

**client_max_body_size** does not limit the size of an upload. The upload must be set by the server administrator in the .ini file or you may be able to modify the value within a .htaccess file; [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992376/how-to-set-upload-max-filesize-in-htaccess).

Comment: php.ini? I already have upload limits set in the websites conf dir : php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 200M
php_admin_value post_max_size 400M
php_admin_value memory_limit 450M
so why do I have to mess with the php.ini now? I put these settings in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/conf/vhost.conf just so I didn't have to set server wide upload limits, I only want these values for one website.

Comment: Try changing the **client_body_timeout** (on your nginx configuration) for something bigger (300, maybe).

The client_max_body_size should limit the content of the headers, but not the file size. Hope **this** one does help you :)

Comment: wow lots of crap to set up in nginx.conf, I added your suggestion and already had added these in the past :
  proxy_connect_timeout       800;
  proxy_send_timeout          800;
  proxy_read_timeout          800;
  send_timeout                800;
...it's like are you going to allow me to upload a semi-large file now without giving me freekin errors? lol anyway tried an upload still getting this connection timeout and had client_body_timeout 800; set then restarted nginx. Any other ideas?

Comment: LOL... It may work (nothing to lose anyway :P). I've found this on the internet: http://snikolau.com/blog/2011-11/upload-nginx-connection-reset/

Comment: ok I did the reboot, didn't work. Now trying some stuff out of the link you sent, reboot again and see how it goes.

Comment: no still not working... this is getting stupid now. Anyone got an answer to this "The connection was reset" problem? If I upload 120MB file or under it works fine, but 130MB plus is no go, so whats the cause???

Comment: Your first answer seems to be incorrect according to this https://github.com/AKSW/OntoWiki/issues/146 in that client_max_body_size does govern upload size. Regardless, I changed it in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and it doesn't seem to change the value in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/conf/last_nginx.conf which is still set to 128M... it kindof explains also why 120MB file uploads without a problem and 130MB doesn't yeah? So anyway, wtf... where do I change this? lol

Comment: Dude you sent me in the wrong direction, it's all about client_max_body_size apparently http://developer24hours.blogspot.com.au/2013/03/nginx-client-intended-to-send-too-large.html cheers for that... my question still remains, how do I get that value to change in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/conf/last_nginx.conf I have already changed  /etc/nginx/nginx.conf but that does nothing to the file in question, it remains at 128M

Comment: who is the silly goose pressing on vote up... the issue remains and there has also been a similar question asked I just found that was not answered correctly by anyone http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16927479/plesk-nginx-uploading-issue vote down...

Comment: Hmm, sorry then for misleading you... it's just that the reset connection is related to the waiting time of the link between the server and the client, so I thought that modifying the client_body_timeout would solve the problem (I still think that's related to the timeout - maybe both things).